# Копирование файлов на локальной машине (http, js)

Tags: javascript, http

**Добрый день всем!**

Достаточно странная задача. Необходимо посредством Html странички скопировать файл (грубо говоря в в html есть 2 поля: destination, source и необходимо переименовать файл, перенести).

**Откуда растут корни (предыстория):**

Делаю загрузчик для STM32 (обновление прошивки).
Появилась такая идея:

- я подключаю устройство по USB.
- устройство определяется как Mass Storage Device (MSD).
- пользователь на устройстве видит инструкцию по обновлению прошивки (readme.txt, в котором написано "замените файл прошивки")
- дальше пользователь может просто заменить файл прошивки и со стороны STM32 данные принимаются и прошивка обновляется.

К этому хочется иметь какой-нибудь пользовательский интерфейс. Я себе напридумывал следующее: MSD может содержать autorun файл, который будет предложен для запуска пользователю в момент, когда MSD проинициализируется. В качестве кроссплатформенного языка, интерпретатор которого стоит почти на любой машине я пока что остановился свой выбор на HTML и на Javascript. Быстро нарисовал интерфейс, который принимает файл и теперь мне его нужно записать в ту же директорию, где находится файл index.html. И пока что я нашел решение только для IE. Для других браузеров решения пока нет. Решение может заключаться не только в копировании файла, но и в запуске внешнего скрипта. Я понимаю, что подобные действия очень небезопасны и поэтому они в большинстве своем закрыты и обрезаны. Как быть?

Comment: Никак, браузер так не умеет. У вас есть два пути: 1 - писать на другом языке. 2 - попробовать electron.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko А что такое electron?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=electron&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUZ780UZ780&oq=electron&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l5j69i60.2679j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 - 
Electron — это фреймворк для разработки настольных приложений с использованием HTML, CSS и JavaScript. Такие приложения могут работать на различных платформах. Среди них — Windows, Mac и Linux. В основе Electron лежат проекты Chromium и Node

Comment: Не годится, требует установки ноды на хосте. А это не на каждой машине есть

Comment: Гм, где вы такое прочитали, что нужно nodejs отдельно как-то ставить?

Comment: Ну примеры, которые я нашёл для линукс прямо начинаются с того, что поставьте ноду.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko А можно простой пример такого приложения и как его запустить. Разбираться с новой технологией требует много усилий.

Comment: Поставьте nodejs для разработки. В итоговом "приложении" ничего отдельно ставить не придется, все будет упаковано в один exe. Простой пример? Поищите hello world для electron, здесь я такой ответ дать не могу, потому что в простом примере будут файлы конфигурации в основном.

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start или скачайте готовое https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Я попробовал. НЕ годится такой вариант, получается слишком большой файл, который мне просто не поместить в загрузчик. кажется, что этот вариант не годится. Я не могу интерпретировать скрипт на лету, а должен собрать приложение. Да проще сделать bat файл и в нем все сделать.

Comment: Гм, в вопросе никаких ограничений на размер приложения не было)) А разве можно написать кроссплатформенный bat файл?

Comment: В самом вопросе конечно нет никаких ограничений, но в предыстории я говорю о STM32, у меня на нем всего 256кБ памяти, чтобы загрузчик был маленьким приходится делать так. Под виндой замечательно работает бат (454 Б) для линукса есть sh. Но хотелось иметь скриптовый язык, который бы позволил из тех инструментов, что есть на любой машине запустить графический интерфейс без особого труда

Comment: Все давно мечтают о таком, что бы работало на всех платформах, был UI, и что бы ничего стороннего не надо было ставить (.net, jvm), весил мало и работал быстро. Мечты мечты...